# Why Flux.zip accept predefined Function but not an anonymous function?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flux

when learning *Flux* (reactive-core) in `java`, I meet following questions about Function.

This is `Flux.zip()` method signature:

```
 public static <I, O> Flux<O> zip(
      final Function<? super Object[], ? extends O> combinator, 
                    Publisher<?extends I>... sources) {
   return zip(combinator, Queues.XS_BUFFER_SIZE, sources);
}
```

And when I try to invoke this method:

```
Flux<User> userFluxFromStringFlux(Flux<String> usernameFlux, Flux<String> firstnameFlux, Flux<String> lastnameFlux) {
        // predefined function taking object[] and returns User
        Function<Object[], User> function = array -> new User(array[0].toString(),array[1].toString(), array[2].toString());
        // it is working without error 
        Flux.zip(function, usernameFlux, firstnameFlux, lastnameFlux);


        // this is also working without error
        Flux.zip(array -> {
            return new User(array[0].toString(),array[1].toString(), array[2].toString());
            }, usernameFlux, firstnameFlux, lastnameFlux);


        // but this has error with array[0] "Array type expected； found: 'org.reactivestreams.subscriber<capture<? super java.lang.object>>'"
        Flux.zip(array ->  new User(array[0].toString(),array[1].toString(), array[2].toString()), usernameFlux, firstnameFlux, lastnameFlux);
        return null;
    }
```

The third way which using anonymous function, but IDEA reports that there is a error :

> Array type expected； found: 'org.reactivestreams.subscriber>.

I wonder why predefined Function and anonymous function with explict return is working but anonymous function?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a compiler expert, but I think it has to do with the java compiler seeing an ambiguity with the short form lambda: is what you are passing an inline `Publisher` (since it is a functional interface) or a `Function`?

This confusion is made possible because the short form doesn't have an explicit `return` statement: in the case of the `Publisher` option it would mean you create a `User` to immediately be garbaged collected, but that's not the sort of things the compiler will forbid you to do.

So the target type of the lambda is assumed to be `Publisher`, and thus `array` is inferred to be a `Subscriber`. But then the array index operator is used on it, which surely must be wrong.

On the other hand, putting in the brackets `{ }` removes that ambiguity by having an explicit `return` type that seem to be used in the inference. To the compiler you can no longer be representing a `Publisher`, so the next candidate (`Function`) is used.

Another way of removing the ambiguity is to show the compiler that the `array` is... an array:

```
Flux.zip((Object[] array) -> new User(array[0].toString(),array[1].toString(), array[2].toString())
                , usernameFlux, firstnameFlux, lastnameFlux);
```

Comment: Just to add a little more detail here as to why compiler is seeing two possible types of lambda (`Publisher` vs `Function`) ..... because the _Flux.zip(....)_ method itself contains multiple variations. One with **1** `Function` and **N** `Publisher` varargs. Another with **3** `Publishers`, another with **4** `Publishers`, **5** `Publishers` and so on. This surely will conflict with other types of functional interfaces at other parameter positions. So yes, we need to explicitly tell the compiler, what method we mean.